# Why simulated and calculated t-distribution pdf at degree-of-freedom=1 doesn't match

Tags: probability, distributions, python, t-distribution, numpy

See the attached graph, I am simulating the pdf of t-distribution at different degrees of freedom (dof), when dof is low (e.g. dof=1), why don't they match? Is it because my experiment wasn't done correctly, or is that expected?

The code

```
def t_dist_pdf(t, dof):
    p1 = special.gamma((dof + 1) / 2)
    p2 = np.sqrt(dof * np.pi) * special.gamma(dof / 2)
    p3 = (1 + t ** 2 / dof) ** (- (dof + 1) / 2)
    return p1 / p2 * p3

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12, 6))
axes = axes.ravel()

bins = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
num = int(1e6)

for k, dof in enumerate(range(1, 7)):
    ax = axes[k]
    t_dist_data = np.random.standard_t(df=dof, size=num)
    ax.hist(t_dist_data, bins=bins, normed=True, histtype='step', label='sim. $t$-dist pdf')

    ax.plot(xs, t_dist_pdf(xs, dof), lw=1, alpha=1, label='$t$-dist pdf')
    ax.plot(xs, stats.t.pdf(xs, dof), lw=5, alpha=0.2, label='scipy $t$-dist pdf')
    ax.plot(xs, stats.norm.pdf(xs), lw=1, alpha=1, label='normal pdf')

    ax.legend(fontsize=8)
    ax.set_title('$t$-distribution dof={0}'.format(dof))
plt.tight_layout()
```

I verified my implementation of t-dist pdf by comparing it to [scipy's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html).

The result.

The X and Y axes of all subplots are the same.

PDF:
[image]

**Update**: CDF:
[image]

**Version** info:

python: 3.5.3,
numpy: 1.12.1,
scipy: 0.19.1

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that the histogram of the simulated data integrates to one (I might not be right, because of the tails we can't see.)  Try plotting the CDFs against each other instead of the PDFs and see what you get.

Comment: It's a good idea, I'ved add CDFs, but still there is a gap. I didn't implemented the CDF myself though.

Comment: The prototype for standard_t has dof as a positional parameter; you should do t_dist_data = np.random.standard_t(dof, size=num)

Comment: Try running np.random.standard_t(dof=1,size=1)!

Comment: @P.Windridge, could you please elaborate? Not sure what do you mean. That's exactly the same as what I did though. `dof` and `df=dof` are equivalent

Comment: Try it with a fractional df parameter close to 1, e.g., 1.05 and 0.95.  If the cdf plot looks good, it may be something quirky with the underlying code exactly at 1.  Wouldn't expect it, but I'm not able to test this on my machine ATM.

Comment: Which version exactly of Python are you using?  I just did stats.kstest(np.random.standard_t(1,size=num), 'cauchy') a few times on Python 2.7.6 a few times and got reasonable results (whereas what you've got would almost certainly fail the KS test miserably with that empirical CDF)

Comment: I am not sure what cauchy is, but executing `stats.kstest(np.random.standard_t(1,size=int(1e6)), 'cauchy')` gives me `KstestResult(statistic=0.00089017582046468924, pvalue=0.40643713777769536)`, I did it multiple times, pvalue varies dramatically.

Comment: That first graph of the CDFs doesn't look like it would have a ks statistic of 0.00089 to me...

Comment: @jbowman , yes more like 0.089 :D.  Starting from np.random.seed(0) I got max D = 0.00114... over 10 runs, which is about what I'd expect for a sample of 10^6

Comment: @zyxue, Cauchy is a t-dist(df=1) (pdf $\propto 1/(1+x^2)$)

Comment: I see, thanks, then based on kstest, it's still correct. Maybe due to the way it's plotted? I am still trying to figure out an explanation. Odd it looks all fine for higher dofs

Comment: What does something like
maxd=0
for i in range(0, 10):
 maxd = max(stats.kstest(np.random.standard_t(df=1,size=num), 'cauchy').statistic,maxd)
give you?

Comment: it gives 0.00114850313365

Comment: I am deeply suspicious of how you draw the histogram.  In particular, by limiting it to the range $[-5,5]$ and requiring the plot to integrate to unity, you are estimating a *truncated* t-distribution.  For the smaller values of df, an appreciable proportion of its probability lies beyond that range (12.6% for df=1, 3.8% for df=2, *etc*).  Accordingly, your plot of the simulated distribution for df=1 should be about 1/(1-12.6%) = 14% too high, *etc*. Equivalently, you should renormalize the theoretical expressions to account for the truncation.

Comment: That is a good point @whuber - the help page does indeed suggest that points outside the range of bins are discarded and not taken into account for the normalisation.  Probably the same applies for the empirical CDF

Comment: @Wuber is insightful and correct. I will renormalize the theoretical expression properly and post the corrected plots.

Answer (score 3):

wuber pointed out the problem,

> In particular, by limiting it to the range [−5,5][−5,5] and requiring
>   the plot to integrate to unity, you are estimating a truncated
>   t-distribution. For the smaller values of df, an appreciable
>   proportion of its probability lies beyond that range (12.6% for df=1,
>   3.8% for df=2, etc). Accordingly, your plot of the simulated distribution for df=1 should be about 1/(1-12.6%) = 14% too high, etc.
>   Equivalently, you should renormalize the theoretical expressions to
>   account for the truncation.

Here is the fixed code with proper normalization for the theoretical *t*-distribution PDF before comparing it to the simulated one:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 3, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(12, 15))
axes = axes.ravel()

bins = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
delta_bin = bins[1] - bins[0]

xs = (bins[1:] + bins[:-1]) / 2
num = int(1e6)

for k, dof in enumerate(range(1, 7)):
    ax = axes[k]

    # IMPORTANT: used to correct the theorectical pdf 
    # for truncated regions of t dist and gaussian/normal dist
    t_renorm = 1 - stats.t.cdf(bins[0], df=dof) * 2
    g_renorm = 1 - stats.norm.cdf(bins[0]) * 2

    t_dist_data = np.random.standard_t(df=dof, size=num)

    ax.plot(xs, stats.t.pdf(xs, dof) / t_renorm, lw=5, alpha=0.2, color='cyan', label='scipy pdf')
    ax.plot(xs, t_dist_pdf(xs, dof) / t_renorm, lw=1, alpha=1, color='red', label='self implemented pdf')
    ax.plot(xs, stats.norm.pdf(xs) / g_renorm, lw=1, alpha=1, color='black', label='normal pdf')
    ax.hist(t_dist_data, bins=bins, normed=True, histtype='step', color='blue', label='simulated pdf')

    ax.legend(fontsize=10)
    ax.set_title('$t$-distribution PDF dof={0}'.format(dof))
    ax.set_xlim(bins[0], bins[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(0, 0.6)


    ax2 = axes[k + 6]
    ax2.plot(xs, cdf(stats.t.pdf(xs, dof) / t_renorm, delta_bin), lw=5, alpha=0.2, color='cyan', label='scipy cdf')
    ax2.plot(xs, cdf(t_dist_pdf(xs, dof) / t_renorm, delta_bin), lw=1, alpha=1, color='black', label='simulated cdf')
    ax2.plot(xs, cdf(stats.norm.pdf(xs) / g_renorm, delta_bin), lw=1, alpha=1, color='black', label='normal cdf')
    ax2.legend(loc='lower right', fontsize=10)
    ax2.set_title('$t$-distribution CDF dof={0}'.format(dof))
    ax2.set_xlim(bins[0], bins[-1])
    ax2.set_ylim(-0.05, 1.05)
plt.tight_layout()
```

The output
[image]

Now, everything matches.

Comment: +1 We appreciate you taking the time to share your resolution of the issue.  It also shows there is a matter of statistical interest here, not just a programming problem.